# How to match distinct repeated characters

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex in R to match strings in which there is repetition of *two distinct* characters.

```
x <- c("aaaaaaah" ,"aaaah","ahhhh","cooee","helloee","mmmm","noooo","ohhhh","oooaaah","ooooh","sshh","ummmmm","vroomm","whoopee","yippee")
```

This regex matches *all* of the above, including strings such as "mmmm" and "ohhhh" where the repeated letter is the same in the first and the second repetition:

```
grep(".*([a-z])\\1.*([a-z])\\2", x, value = T)
```

What I'd like to match in `x` are these strings where the repeated letters are distinct:

```
"cooee","helloee","oooaaah","sshh","vroomm","whoopee","yippee"
```

How can the regex be tweaked to make sure the second repeated character is not the same as the first?

Comment: `popor` should not match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may restrict the second char pattern with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
grep(".*([a-z])\\1.*(?!\\1)([a-z])\\2", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
#                    ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/92PMyx/1).

`(?!\\1)([a-z])` means *match and capture into Group 2 any lowercase ASCII letter if it is not the same as the value in Group 1*.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/ulgRXq):

```
x <- c("aaaaaaah" ,"aaaah","ahhhh","cooee","helloee","mmmm","noooo","ohhhh","oooaaah","ooooh","sshh","ummmmm","vroomm","whoopee","yippee")
grep(".*([a-z])\\1.*(?!\\1)([a-z])\\2", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
# => "cooee"   "helloee" "oooaaah" "sshh"    "vroomm"  "whoopee" "yippee"
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution @Wiktor. I'm having difficulty understanding the lookahead assertion. I read `.*(?!\\1)` as match 0 or more of any character not proceeded by `\1` - but applying `.*([a-z])\1.*(?!\1)` on `helloel` yields a full match of `helloel` - I don't understand this, shouldn't it just match the `hello` portion of the string? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rDs429/2).

Comment: @user51462 `.*(?!\1)` should not be used like that as `(?!\1)` in my regex restricts the `([a-z])` pattern part. You might have meant `.*([a-z])\1(?!.*\1)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rDs429/3). It will match any string containing 2 consecutive identical letters that cannot be followed with this same char anywhere to the right of the current location. I am not sure if this is your intent though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid regex altogether, then I think that's the way to go. A rough example:

```
nrep <- sapply(
  strsplit(x, ""), 
  function(y) {
     run_lengths <- rle(y)
     length(unique(run_lengths$values[run_lengths$lengths >= 2]))
   }
)
x[nrep > 1]
# [1] "cooee"   "helloee" "oooaaah" "sshh"    "vroomm"  "whoopee" "yippee"
```

Comment: That's an awfully cool solution. I'm not familiar with `rle`. What does it do?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann It will reduces (if there are repititions) one vector to two vectors, `lengths` (of reptitition) and `values` (that are repeated). Simple xample: `rle(c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A"))`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann discovered a corner case and updated solution.